# Is it true that $\|\Sigma-I\|\le\|\Sigma-U\|\le\|\Sigma+I\|$ and why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Where $\Sigma\in M_n$ is a non-negative diagonal matrix, $U$ is any unitary matrix and $\|\bullet\|$ is a unitarily invariant norm.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of norm, we have $$\| \Sigma \| - \| U \| \le \| \Sigma - U \| \le \| \Sigma \| + \| U \|$$

So if the norm is the **spectral norm**, which is unitarily invariant, then $$\| \Sigma \|=\lambda_{max}, \quad \| U \| =1, \quad \| \Sigma \pm I \| = \lambda_{max} \pm 1,$$

where $\lambda_{max}$ is the maximum diagonal element of $\Sigma$. Subsituting these equalities into the above inequality will give the result.

Comment: $\Sigma =0$ is a non-negative diagonal matrix, but $\|\Sigma -I\| = 1$, not zero.